# How to smooth out final polyurethane coat?

Tags: sanding, polyurethane

first time posting here and first time doing any sort of woodworking.

I purchased the Gerton table top from IKEA and it came pretty scratchy. So I sanded it with 120 grit sandpaper and applied 3 coats of polyurethane to it.

For the most part this all seems fine, but the top level feels a bit uneven, and there's some small air bubbles all over the place.

**I was wondering what's the best way to smooth out the top level of polyurethane?** Should I try sanding it?

I've looked online but found contrasting ideas on what to do, so any feedback would be great to hear.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi welcome to SE. Duplicate queries are against the guidelines here so this will be closed in due course as we have multiple existing Q&As that cover this topic from various angles.

Comment: After you've sanded the finish flat you can continue to sand and polish the surface as indicated in the above Q&A, or with less effort you can wipe on diluted varnish and have this produce your final surface (you wipe it on and off your matt, sanded surface). See more on this option in this [Answer](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5891/how-to-fix-very-light-scratches-in-polyurethane-finish/5893#5893).