# Desktop case design: Which one should I do first for mold and heat resistance, epoxy resin or varnish?

Tags: mdf, varnish, epoxy

I'm working on some MDF pieces for some design and thought of using both protective (anti-mold, Polyurethane) varnish and epoxy resin together. Problem is, I don't know which order would be best for the coats.

I saw some people using either but never both (yet) so not sure how to approach this.

The design is a bit weird but: this is for a desktop case. I saw a lot of people on different forums and youtube videos making them, but wanted to make my own design.

I planned on MDF (like some other people). Because I noticed molds was a possible enemy, I wanted to coat it with some Polyurethane varnish, to at least alleviate the "future" problem. Then I thought that the constant heat inside the case (even with good cooling, a desktop case can have roughly 20-30°C in temp, and more under heavy loads) might deteriorate the varnish, so then came the epoxy resin.

I wanted to also just put epoxy resin, at the very least because:

1. it would alleviate the "burned" smell from the pieces I bought since they were laser cut.
2. It would look better on my eye(s)
3. I wanted to try and get a heat-resistant epoxy, since I don't think it would withstand desktop case's normal temperature, at least ***overtime***.

After all of that, I asked myself which one I should put on first, especially when I learned that epoxy might not stick on every surface, and need it to be sanded/roughed, etc to be able to stick.

Any ideas or recommendations?

Comment: Intuition would have me do the resin first (deeper penetration), but that might swell the mdf. So do a test, make sure it works, and then see how the varnish bonds to the epoxy.

Comment: I see :) I did plan on still making experiments with 1. varnish only, 2. epoxy, 3. both on small pieces of MDF to see how they would hold/look like, but still wanted to know in advance (aware it could swell/make the wood thicker but that's not an issue on my end) @AloysiusDefenestrate

Comment: Since you mention coats and you're concerned with order presumably the epoxy isn't being used as a filler so this prompts the first question, why?? The bottom line here is that often there's no point in combining two clear finishes, so there really needs to be a good reason (e.g. big difference in drying time or build). *"Any ideas or recommendations?"* What is it you're trying to achieve? You haven't actually said what the end goal is here.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, are you saying epoxy first because it would penetrate deeper than varnish, or it would because it's the first thing applied? Obviously yes if it's the second thing to go on (penetration could be effectively zero if applied over even a thin coating of varnish if that fully wets the surface) :-)

Comment: I didn't want to mention the "why", since I thought I would be mocked :P updated my post @Graphus

Comment: "this is for a desktop case" - is this a desktop computer case you're building? Internal case temps can get much higher than 30°C. My CPU can be in the 40s and occasional disk temps can peak near 50°C.  Good airflow helps, and the lower the temps the better, but be sure to adjust your expectations.

Comment: That said, I can't fathom what benefits you'd get from using _both_ epoxy and polyurethane. Get products that will support your expected temps (likely that common formulas of both will do just fine, even in a constant air temp of 40°C), apply some to some sample pieces and decide which you prefer. I think this falls into an opinion-based question which is off topic here.

Comment: this isn't falling into an opinion-based question: someone asked me the "why" even though I knew what would happen, so here it is :) if the "why" is opinionated, the question itself taken out of context *isn't* technically  @FreeMan

Comment: @FreeMan re cooling: yes, I did said in my updated post `even with good cooling, a desktop case can have roughly 20-30°C in temp, and more under heavy loads`. :D I monitor temps all the time so I know rough estimate based on the workload and what not

Comment: @FreeMan re benefit: I already detailed the reason and benefit for both of the coatings. It's just that I'm unsure which one I should use first, or if there better alternative.

Comment: I'm not aware of mold on MDF being an issue, but it may be in your locale. I'm not aware of either epoxy coated or PU coated items molding, either, indicating that either should suffice to prevent mold. I believe that both would be sufficiently heat resistant enough to stand up to your design criteria. Therefore, I don't understand why you want to do both. However, it's your project, so carry on.

Comment: so you're saying that I don't necessarily need both, and that either of them will suffice for what I described above? I mean I would understand for the resin, but I thought the varnish would deteriorate faster under constant heat compared to epoxy? (I might be just misunderstanding, so feel free to correct me) @FreeMan

Comment: Your edit ads some interesting details that I wish we could get into more easily here but obviously there's limited scope for that on SE. [If you want to get a better picture of this I recommend posting about your project on one of the forums] So in short: 1, this will naturally go away in time all on its own! 2, why does this matter *inside the case where you normally aren't looking*?? 3. What's your expectation for how long you'll want to hold on to this case before you want to replace it for something cooler/better, or just new? Based on my experience of custom PCs I bet it's not 10 years!

Comment: So, since oil-based polyurethane can withstand the typical temps in a working kitchen — *way* higher than your quoted figures for inside temps (and far more challenging due to the high humidity) and still give a working life well in excess (honestly, maybe triple or more!) of what I bet your answer to no. 3 is....

Comment: sorry for not adding those details earlier on :) I really thought this would be questioned more than it was, so I'm glad this wasn't too harshly received (although I guess the score on this question kind of gives another impression). Ah, you got me for 1, and 2. I want to say for 3. too but there isn't enough space to go into details as you said...btw, can you give more details on those other "forums"? @Graphus

Comment: I just meant any of the existing woodworking forums out there online, since the standard threaded forum (or the Reddit 'equivalent') is much better geared to asking a question and then going off on a few different tangents simultaneously as the discussion flows. Because of the unknown level of competence/knowledge of the people who'll respond I regret to say that you definitely do still have to do your due diligence (bootstrap yourself) so you don't build houses of cards based on any of a number of poorly understood concepts or outright myths, surprisingly widespread even with the Internet :-(

Comment: yeah, I see what you mean. Even though my choice of using MDF was because of how cheap it is compared to other materials (eg: aluminum, etc), I still want to save money, so I plan on making more simulations, measurements, and looking up what people do in x,y,z, etc. I guess I might ask on other forums at some point, but for now, I think using common sense and a lot of personal research should yield some decent results :D appreciate the recommendation. @Graphus

Comment: If there's mold growing inside your computer case you have bigger problems than the case finish.

Comment: exactly, that's why I wanted to know in advance which one I should do first when I use both, to increase the probability of having mold growing @gnicko

Comment: I should have pointed this out earlier too, but when I say "mold", I mean "Powdery mildew".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discussion was getting carried away, so here we go:

#### Heat resistance

Polyurethane is very heat resistant [-62°C to 93°C](https://gallaghercorp.com/polyurethane-temperature-range/) with special formulations able to handle temps as high as 150°C, however that's in a solid, cast or molded form.

All other search results I've looked at for "heat resistant polyurethane wood finish" come up with concerns about putting hot items directly from the stove or oven on a woodworking-finish polyurethane-coated table. [This Woodworking.SE answer](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/a/11613/93), however, indicates that a poly coat *may* have been what was used on the question's table that was, in fact, cooking-hot pot heat resistant for several decades.

Considering that the internal case temperatures aren't likely to be anywhere near those of a pot off the stove or casserole dish out of the oven, I'd think that it's quite likely that your finish will hold up to temps into the 40°C range for quite some time.

Alternatively, you are considering an epoxy coating. Epoxy can be had in quite a number of formulations, including very high temperature resistant ones, so it's a simple matter of choosing one that suits your expected conditions. According to [this site](https://www.thecreativefolk.com/is-epoxy-heat-resistant/):

> Unfortunately, epoxy resin is not heat resistant. Epoxy resin can only withstand heat up to 302°F. Fortunately, there are many types of hard-curing resins, and each has a different degree of heat resistance.

Note that epoxy can "only" withstand temps up to 302°F (150°C) and that's a fair bit above what your computer components will produce.  Right out of the box with epoxy you're at the upper end of what polyurethane can take so you probably won't need to look for any sort of special heat-resistant epoxy coatings - just about any common wood working epoxy should do the trick.

#### Mold resistance

According to [this site](https://www.precisionurethane.com/urethane-advantage.html):

> **Mold, Mildew & Fungus Resistance**
> Most polyether based polyurethanes do not support fungal, mold and mildew growth and are therefore highly suitable for tropical environments. Special additives can also be added to reduce this in polyester materials as well.

To be honest, I don't know if polyurethane based wood finishes are polyether based, so it would be wise to do some research on the particular brand you're considering. By "doing research", I really mean "contact the vendor and explicitly ask", as that would get you the most accurate answer. However, it does appear that *most* PU finishes *are* mold resistant, so that shouldn't be a concern for you either.

According to [this site](https://www.masterbond.com/industrial-applications/epoxies-resist-mildew-mold-fungus-biological-growth):

> Master Bond epoxy systems are non-nutrient and do not sustain or support mildew/mold/fungi or biological growth.

Now, this specifically talks about one brand of epoxy, but note that it says "non-nutrient". I can't imagine that there are any ingredients in any epoxy formulation that would actively support the growth of mold. (I take this claim to be much like the "Gluten Free!" label on a package of bacon. Gluten is from wheat, and there shouldn't be any wheat product in bacon.)

Of course, no matter what coating you use, if there are mold spores in the air, they can land on *any* surface and if they get enough humidity and enough nutrients landing on them from other airborne sources, mold will grow. However, there's no indication that either polyurethane or epoxy will directly support mold growth any more than a piece of steel would.

#### Summary

This indicates that neither heat nor mold resistance are going to be significant concerns for your computer case. Therefore, you're free to choose your finish treatment as you desire without worry about either of these concerns.

One thing that you should be concerned about but didn't bring up is that MDF is *exceptionally* vulnerable to water. Anything more than average humidity exposure will cause the MDF to absorb moisture and start to swell. Once this happens, your material is shot and it's time to replace it - there's no repairing swollen MDF. This leads to a decision that provides the most water resistance for the MDF and that would, I would think, point me toward epoxy rather than poly.

Another concern is that MDF is not a particularly *pretty* material to work with and you'll probably want to hide it. Polyurethane coatings are, basically, clear (slightly yellowing, but basically clear). This has the tremendous disadvantage of showing off the bland MDF below. Epoxy, on the other hand, can be had (or made) in a multitude of colors, allowing you to hide the material beneath, even allowing you to match the case to your decor, should you desire.

All in all, I would use a colored epoxy for this situation, however, that's down to an aesthetic choice which is opinion based and, therefore off-topic for a question here. Functionally, I think either material would work well with a slight advantage to the epoxy.

---

Note: No endorsement of any of the web sites used as references or their products is implied or intended. They were chosen solely based upon their order of appearance in search results and for their ability to supply supporting data.

Comment: this is so detailed..Thanks a lot! :D (also didn't thought of humidity/water damage, very good point)

Comment: Sadly, it took more time for me to write up an answer than it did to search the internet for the information, which is what the OP could easily have done. :/

Comment: ah, sorry about that. I did find some good links that explained that using both, or one after the other works in X cases, but I really wanted to see what could be said in this site.