# Oil-based polyurethane became cloudy after sanding and wiping with moist cloth

Tags: finishing, sanding, polyurethane, moisture

I applied a thick coat of oil poly. Once dry, it looked clear in color. However, it was very rough and uneven, so I sanded heavily. After hours of sanding, I wiped the sawdust off with a moist cloth. The color of the poly turned all milky and cloudy. It looks so horrible now. What do I do? Can I fix this?

Comment: What grit did you sand to? And have you tried applying another coat?

Comment: 220 grit. No, I'm afraid to apply another coat over the cloudiness

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. My first instinct is to say, you sanded the surface, of course it's cloudy now ^_^ There could be more going on here but the first thing we need to check is does the varnish look fine if you wet it now? If so then no need to panic, there's a dead easy fix and [this Q&A](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5891/how-to-fix-very-light-scratches-in-polyurethane-finish) will sort you out. And of course as a follow-on from that for future varnishing jobs I would highly highly recommend doing the whole job with wiping varnish as it's so forgiving.

Comment: This feels like an almost exact duplicate of the link provided by @Graphus.

Comment: @jdv, yes it is, if the cloudiness goes away when the surface is wet with water.

Comment: Thanks @Graphus! Yes, it looks completely fine when I wet it. This answers my question.