# Finish choice for my wooden essential-oil container

Tags: finishing, finish-selection

I built a wooden container to hold all my essential oils. I’m having trouble figuring out what type of finish I should apply. I want one that has resistance in case anything spills. So a finish resistant to oil and alcohol would be best.

Should I do an oil finish and spray it with polyurethane? Or go straight to a poly wipe-on? Or is there a better finish that has a higher oil/alcohol resistance?

Comment: I completely forgot to add anything on this bit *"Or is there a better finish that has a higher oil/alcohol resistance?"* As you might expect, there are finishes with strengths far above the levels available in consumer-level products, the type of thing that might be chosen to finish bartops or counters in a commercial space, bistro tables, etc. This includes things like catalysed lacquer, two-pack polyurethane (completely different to oil-based polys), epoxy and polyester coatings. But in addition to their cost all or virtually all require spray equipment to apply, & they tend to be v. toxic.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I do an oil finish and spray it with polyurethane ?

As mentioned in a number of previous Answers, often there is no benefit to oiling wood prior to adding poly. Where you may want to do this is to maximise colour contrast/figure in the wood but oil-based varnishes are already quite good at doing this.

> Or go straight to a poly wipe on?

There are a number of modern finish types that tout oil and alcohol resistance that you could roll the dice on, but for maximum resistance you really need a film finish. And for a number of reasons wiping on poly is what I would have recommended anyway.

In addition to being relatively inexpensive and easy to get, oil-based polyurethane varnish is the easiest highly protective finish to apply to a high standard (irrespective of the shapes involved). See the images in [this previous Answer](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5891/how-to-fix-very-light-scratches-in-polyurethane-finish/5893#5893) on making it yourself. Note you don't have to wipe it on if you'd prefer not to, what makes the technique so forgiving is not wiping it on, but *wiping off the excess*. You can wipe off some, most or all of the excess as per your preference.

Oil-based poly comes with some attendant solvent odour (there's some in the formula already, when making a commercial wiping varnish they simply add more spirits.... and overcharge for it).

I thought someone who is into essential oils might appreciate a little on reducing the associated smells, especially since you're likely to be working indoors given the season.

**A note on reducing solvent odour**
If you want to reduce the smell of the thinned varnish, dilute it with "OMS" (odourless mineral spirits) or low-odour mineral spirits. The products in this category vary in just how "odourless" they are. Expect to pay more for any that have virtually no odour, but even a basic type should not have any offensive smell of the mineral spirits type.