# To keep a debossed look of a resin filled etching, should I stain before or after?

Tags: staining

I have a couple projects that I'm completing at request for a friend with a specific vision where I'm epoxy resin filling an engraved oak surface. I've completed the current piece already but wanna perfect it for the next. I initially stained (green tinted minwax wood finish water-based solid color stain), sealed (matte poly), taped off, engraved, sealed, and then epoxy resin filled (tinted with alcohol ink and micca). I still had some depth with the resin filled engraving that I wanted but the look isn't as clean as I could wish. What order would be best if I wanted to maintain the debossed/indented look of the resin filled engraving (NOT flush with the wood like I see with a lot of resin fill projects) but still be able stain the wood without effecting the color of the resin? What would the best wood, resin and stain be?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. The general way you do this is covered in a previous Q&A, [In which order should I glue, stain and apply epoxy resin?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/10413/in-which-order-should-i-glue-stain-and-apply-epoxy-resin/10417#10417) To go beyond this and deliberately stain at the start you're going to have to do your own experiments, there are just too many variables to predict outcomes reliably (plus your own standards for what's acceptable will be the final determinant, not what someone else considers acceptable).

Comment: I'm going to mark this Q as a dupe of the previous one I linked to above because in theory at least this could be done the same way, given the right materials. Feel free to stick around and ask any other Questions as needed, but be aware SE highly values previous research (which should be mentioned in the body text) and most importantly this includes a search of the existing Q&As so that there's minimum chance of a duplicate. Also, as much as possible it's one question per Question here. See [the Tour](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/tour) for more details on how to ask a good Question.

Comment: I appreciate your responding, @Graphus. I specifically read that question before asking mine. That one is for flush resin fill, which is not what I'm going for. I highly value previous research as well and not wasting anyone else's time, let alone my own when a search would answer my question if possible. You seem knowledgeable, having answered the linked question. You don't have any other advice besides experiment?

Comment: *"You don't have any other advice besides experiment?"* No I'm afraid not because the species (not to mention individual boards and how their grain runs relative to the incised pattern) are sure to interact with the resin in so many complex ways. You might have seen some of what I'm getting at already given you didn't get as clean a result as you wished for. So experimentation might be the only way to get useful insights into achieving the look you're going for, unless you can find a forum where one or more members have done similar work and you get discuss strategies with them.

Comment: Again, I appreciate you responding Graphus, thanks. I'm just a novice when it comes to this and was hoping for some direction. It's intimidating and discouraging to see that based on your knowledge (which seems to be extensive, considering your standing in SE) I will likely not be able to find a consistent method for this unless I use the same species, find a similarly grain of wood and do the same engraving each time. I apologize if my question came across as a dupe. I admit it seemed similar but I thought it really was unique. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Don't worry you didn't waste anyone's time. We're here to help. Or try to at least — unfortunately the strict question-and-answer format on SE limits the kind of queries that can be dealt with successfully here. Open-ended and multi-part queries are best dealt with in a conventional forum environment and with some luck you can get helpful input that lasts days, sometimes longer. Plus every woodworking forum I know, even the ones experiencing 'dry' patches, have *far* larger active memberships than Woodworking does so there's a much bigger pool of knowledge to potentially draw from.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In which order should I glue, stain and apply epoxy resin?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/10413/in-which-order-should-i-glue-stain-and-apply-epoxy-resin)

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I had read that post before posting mine. That's for a flush epoxy resin fill. Mine is for a debossed epoxy resin fill.